# div wrapping with float

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 divs, one I want to float left, the video player (loaded with jquery), another that contains some help/tips text that will float right. These two should be lined up at the top. Under the video player will be a table inside a div.

When someone clicks a button in the table a new div should be placed on the left in between the video player and table. Here is my code:

```
<div id="player-ipad"></div>
<div id="help-tips-ipad">
<p><img src="images/help-35-30.png" style="padding:8px;" align="left"/><h2 style="color:black;">Help Resources</h2><hr>
<p>Read our <a href="http://www.mysite.com/support/articles/quickstart-page">Quickstart Guide</a></p>
<p>Visit our <a href="http://www.mysite.com/support">Support Forum</a> and ask a question</p>
</p>
<p><img src="images/quicktip-35-30.png" style="padding:8px;" align="left"/><h2 style="color:black;">Tips</h2><hr>
<ul>
<li>Help tips here.</li>
<li>More tips.</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div id="quote"><p></p></div>

<div id="prettytablediv-ipad">
<p>
<table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Camera Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{

?>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="submit" class="play" data-type="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"]; ?>" data-hash="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>">
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
</div>
```

The css I have is:

```
#prettytablediv-ipad {
    width: 550px;
    float: left;
}
#help-tips-ipad {
    width: 320px;
    float: right;
}
#player-ipad {
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background-image:url(../../images/videoPlaceHolder01.JPG);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

The fourth div that comes into place when someone clicks a button:

```
$(document).on("click", ".play", function() {
   $('#quote p').html("INFO").css({'border': '1px solid', 'margin': '10px 0px', 'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': '10px center', 'color': '#00529B', 'background-color': '#BDE5F8', 'width': '320px','display': 'block','clear': 'left'});
});
```

Someone helped me with this earlier and here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HgyB/11/) showing it works perfectly. But I've made all the changes to my code and can't see why I can't make it to work like the fiddle.

My results show the table right under the helps/tips text instead of the left side. It seems to be wrapped beside it. Plus now when someone clicks a button the info message is above the table (which is right, but they both should be aligned left).

Because the table (`#prettytablediv-ipad`) is floating left beside the help/tips it would go to stand that using `clear:left` would fix this, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lot of unclosed tags

```
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

everything has been wrapped with div #help-tips-ipad

```
#help-tips-ipad {
width: 320px;
float: right;
]
```

Comment: I thought my code was okay and this was a typo. Good catch. Thx!